# How to send Post with parameters

Tags: c#, http-post, httprequest

I want to send POST with parameters, but I don't know how to do it.

My code:

```
 Uri resourceAddress = new Uri("http://web.com/geo");
 try
 {
    HttpResponseMessage response=await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress,
        new HttpStringContent("")).AsTask(cts.Token);
 }
 catch (Exception ex) { }
 finally { }
```

How can I send a post with this code like: `{ latitude:-1.323141, lng:24.42342 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You populate the HttpContent with the key/values you want to send over.

Specifically:

```
Uri resourceAddress = new Uri("http://web.com/geo");
var values = new Dictionary<string, double>
{
   { "latitude", -1.323141 },
   { "lng", 24.42342 }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

try{
    HttpResponseMessage response=await httpClient.PostAsync(resourceAddress,
         content).AsTask(cts.Token);
 } catch (Exception ex){
 }finally{

 }
```